# Is it possible to disable scroll on a listView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I dynamically add items to a `ListView` and want to make all the items always visible, without scrolling.

Layout Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/recipe_inside"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/head_cella" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:background="@drawable/body_cella"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="Remember to save before leaving this page or inserted/modified data will be lost."
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/head_cella" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/body_cella"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/head_cella" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/body_cella"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/recipe_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Recipe title" android:lines="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/head_cella" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/body_cella"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="Ingredients"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
         <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" android:divider="#00000000"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            >
       </ListView>

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/button_ing"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="" android:background="@drawable/add_recipe_button" android:onClick="addItems"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView></LinearLayout>
```

old OnCreate() function code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_recipe_form);

    spinner = (Spinner)myhead.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);

    Cursor cursor = mydb.getCategoriesList();
    ArrayList<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();
    list.add(new Category(0,"Choose a category"));

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(new Category(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1))); 
    }
    // Step 2: Create and fill an ArrayAdapter with a bunch of "State" objects
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    // Step 3: Tell the spinner about our adapter
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);   
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ingredients.add((View)findViewById(R.layout.row_add_recipe));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If I move code related to fill my spinner with database data, it always returns me a NullPointerException as it's not found in my layout. So I need to keep it here and the solution adding addHeaderView() to my ListView seems to be ok, but I have another NullPointerException regarding my head layout:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.add_recipe_form);
    ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    LinearLayout myhead = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_form);
    mylistview.addHeaderView(myhead);
    spinner = (Spinner)myhead.findViewById(R.id.category_spinner);

    Cursor cursor = mydb.getCategoriesList();
    ArrayList<Category> list = new ArrayList<Category>();
    list.add(new Category(0,"Choose a category"));

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        list.add(new Category(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1))); 
    }
    // Step 2: Create and fill an ArrayAdapter with a bunch of "State" objects
    ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

    // Step 3: Tell the spinner about our adapter
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);   
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ingredients.add((View)findViewById(R.layout.row_add_recipe));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: `make all items visible without scrolling` What if you have items more than your screen size?

Comment: could you please explain it in more detail? How should your items be displayed, when you add too much items for the screen to display (e.g. you added 100 items)?

Comment: my ListView is inside a Linearlayout that has other elements inside, which is in a ScrollView.

Comment: ListView inside a ScrollView is a bad idea. If you want to have others elements apart from the ListView and everything scrollable, I would put these elements within a row and use a ListView as parent instead of ScrollView.

Comment: @miguel.rodelas I added my layout code. As you can see I have several elements above my listview. You're saying that I should make a different row layout for every element I have above  my ListView and add them to my ListView instead of using the ScrollView as a container for them?

Comment: @dany84 I answered with another option for your case. From my experience, ListView within a ScrollView is not a good idea and I would go with the 2nd option. Let me know if I can help you in something else.

Comment: Are you just trying to have a scrollable listView but with some content above it and/or below it also scrollable? If so - use header and footer in your listview. The way you're trying to implement it is far from optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you well, you just need some more views wich are scrollable along with your listview. The best way to implement it is to call [`addHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and [`addFooterView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) on your `ListView()`.

**EDIT:**

It should go like this, I think:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_main_layout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_header_layout); //R.layout, not R.id!

    (ListView) list = findViewById(android.R.list);
    list.addHeaderView(header);

    list.setAdapter(adapter); //according to docs you should call setAdapter() after addHeaderView()

    //to get the spinner
    (Spinner) spinner = (Spinner) header.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

}
```

I'm writing from memory and didn't test it, but I think it should work. Try it out when you get a moment.

Comment: That's interesting. I've created a new XML layout file for my head but when I use this code: LinearLayout myhead = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_form); it returns me "null". Any idea?

Comment: Where do you call it? In `onCreate()` of your activity?

Comment: yes, I call it on the OnCreate(). If it could be useful, here is part of my OnCreate() function: setContentView(R.layout.add_recipe_form);
  ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  LinearLayout myhead = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_form);
  mylistview.addHeaderView(myhead);

Comment: You can't just get a layout from a separate xml file with findViewById. You should inflate `R.layout.linear_form` with `getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE).inflate(R.layout.linear_form)`. That's because the scope of `id` is the xml file specified in `setContentView()`

Comment: Hope it helps, if not, try reading something about inflating views. I'm going to an exam now and will be available a little bit later

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read something about this, as I don't know how to use your code. I'll let you know!

Comment: I inflated that layout, but the problem was always the same, I can't reach my spinner by id to fill it, so your solution doesn't fit for me unfortunately.

Comment: When you inflate a view, you have a reference to it. Just put the reference in addHeaderView and you're there. No need for id. I'll write you the code in an hour or so, if you still can't do it

Comment: And if your spinner is inside this header view, you get the spinner by referencing this header too. Like: headerview.findViewById(R.id.spinner)

Comment: I've tried to do so, but it didn't work, I don't know exactly why, now I've completely changed my code using TableLayout and it works as I need to. Thank you anyway, but I was in a hurry and had to resolve it fast.

Comment: It may work, but you're taking away all these nice things associated with ListView, like e.g. one listener instead of several, plus you're nesting layouts deeper. It will work for sure, but will consume more memory, will work slower and will be harder to maintain later. Just my two cents;)

Comment: Thank you again, I'm a newbie, didn't know about these differences between the two views. I'll try to find some more time to use ListView again then!

Comment: Used AddHeaderView and addFooterView for another ListView, and it worked!! I'll try in a few days to modify this one with the spinner. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to do the ListView height as big as the content. You can achieve this effect using the following class instead of ListView:

```
public class ExpandedListView extends ListView {

  private int old_count = 0;

  public ExpandedListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getCount() != old_count) {
        old_count = getCount();
        int totalHeight = 0;
        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getWidth(), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = getAdapter().getView(i, null, this);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (getDividerHeight() * (getCount() - 1));
        setLayoutParams(params);
        requestLayout();
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

}
```

Anyway, it's a bad idea to have a ListView within a ScrollView, so I would add the other elements in your Layout as a header/footer view with the methods addHeaderView() and addFooterView() as MichałK pointed out.

Here you have an example about how to use these methods:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/HeaderFooter

Comment: No need to get specific items in the listview. `addHeaderView()` and `addFooterView()` does the trick easier.

Comment: Are these header/footer fixed and always visible? I think he wants everything to be scrollable.

Comment: These are scrollable, just some custom views added as a row to the list. Plus, you can add several of them or just put there a `LinearLayout` with other views, so it's a nice, customizable solution

Comment: Thank you. I have several problems with your solution, as I can't fill my spinner dinamically putting it along with other elements as a row of my ListView. I'm not trying your code for the custom view as you said that it's not an optimal solution.

Comment: @MichałK In that case, addHeaderView and addFooterView are the best way

Comment: @dany84 which problems do you have with the spinner? It would be useful if you add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `ListView` **height** bigger than your **content size**.

say if You have **5 listitems** each **having 20sp height** set list view **height to 100 or greater**
this way you can achieve it

Comment: This way he can achieve a non-scrollable `ListView` but there are better ways to achieve the ultimate goal which is to have some views sorround the `ListView` and get scrolled along. As it's been already mentioned, putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView` is a bad idea

Comment: This can be automatically achieved with the ExpandedListView I copied in the answer, but it's far from optimal.

Comment: I get a ClassCastException trying to modifying layout params of my listview as I add a new item.

Comment: this is my function to add dinamically items to my listview and I added the code to set height dinamically every time I add an item.    public void addItems(View v) {
     ingredients.add(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_recipe_row, null));
     ListView mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
     mylistview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,(mylistview.getHeight()+100)));
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: try casting int(mylistview.getHeight())